# This happen when openin gdesktop

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, software-installation, usb

This is happen when I open my laptop
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O6LMKhGEwCjpVHRwULFc25LjF0hNusXU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this an ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.